# Installing ActiveSync SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, activesync

I know very little about activesync setup on mobile devices. I have a Samsung SGH-i900 running Windows Mobile 6.1

We are running Exchange in the company. I know from reading through google that a certificate will be needed to be installed on the device, but don't know where to find it and when it is found where to put it on the device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I will answer what I did incase others read this.

On the exchange server in the C: drive there are SSL certificates. On of these was the active certificate. Copy them to your computer.

Connect the PDA to your computer and copy the certificates to the device through explorer.

On the PDA go to 'File Explorer' and locate the certificates. Double tap them to install them on the PDA.

Once this is done go through ActiveSync and put in all the necessary user information. Note: make sure that your AD profile has 'Remote Allowed' checked.

After this, all is working well.